# How to replace dots to numbers to letters in Slick.js?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Below is the code where the dots were replaced with numbers previously. But I wanted to replace the numbers to letters this time. You can check the demo website at http://pegu2.onpressidium.com/ and the issue under the section "Exploring The Pegu Club".

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clearly explain your issue, can you please edit to make more sense?

Comment: I apologize for not explaining clearly. On the demo website at http://pegu2.onpressidium.com/ and the issue under the section "Exploring The Pegu Club", the slider can be navigated via the red markers with numbers. I was wondering how to change this numbers into letters.

Comment: The `php` code is not relevant here . `Slick.js` is a client side library .

Comment: Add any relevent code to your question here on SO. Don't link towards another website where the issue is explained or can be "seen". That website will not stay online forever and your question will become completely useless for others that might have the same (or a very similar) question in the future. _"Below is the code"_ <-- no, there is not. You should read about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding to your question , please check the following working example .

```js
var letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];

$(".slider").slick({
    autoplay: false,
    dots: true,
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
    var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data();
    
    return '<a>'+letters[i]+'</a>';
            },
    responsive: [{ 
        breakpoint: 500,
        settings: {
            dots: false,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        } 
    }]
});
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
}

.slick-slide {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev:before, 
.slick-next:before {
    color: black;    
}

.slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
}

.slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
     background: gray;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.js"></script>

<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! Apologies for the last time but how can I implement the solution in this function:

jQuery('#explore-image-slider').slick({
       arrows: false,
       fade: true,
       asNavFor: '#explore-text-slider',
       dots: true,
           customPaging: function(slick,index) {
               //return '<a>' + (index + 1) + '</a>';
               return '<div class="marker marker-' + (index + 1) + '"><span>' + (index + 1) + '</span></div>'
           }
     });

Comment: 1) Put the `letters` Array somewhere above this snippet . 2) Replace `<div class="marker marker-' + (index + 1) + '"><span>' + (index + 1) + '</span></div>` with `<div class="marker marker-' + (index + 1) + '"><span>' + letters[index + 1] + '</span></div>`

Comment: I've updated the demo site and worked like magic!!! The only problem is it started with letter B and not with A.

Comment: Fixed now! I added a blank "var letter" before letter A. Thanks! You're the man!

Comment: Then replace`index+1` with `index` :)

Comment: Yea ,this is possible also . None professional though :) . Removing the `+1` is more easier and clearer . Don't forget to mark the answer as Correct .

Comment: @FerlinFrange If someone helped you out and solved your problem, please make sure to click the checkmark next to their answer. This will mark your question as answered and shows your appreciation to the person that helped you out.

Comment: @Ashraf Thanks for bearing with me being new to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @icecub Noted and will do better next time with your tips!